# Let $p$ be prime. Prove if $p|(a^p - b^p)$, then $p^2 | (a^p - b^p)$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $p$ be prime. Prove if $p|(a^p - b^p)$, then $p^2 | (a^p - b^p)$

don't know where to begin, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  $a^p\cong b^p\pmod p\implies a\cong b\pmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem.

So you can write $a=b+k\cdot p$.

So, look at $(b+k\cdot p)^p-b^p$ and use the binomial theorem.

(Remember,  $p\choose n$ is divisible by $p$ for $0\lt n\lt p$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let p|(*a^p - b^p*)
Therefore p can be written as *p=k**(*a^p - b^p*)
so *p^2* becomes *k^2**(*a^p - b^p*)^*2*
or, *p^2*=*p***k**(*a^p - b^p*)
hence, *p^
2*
|(
*a^
p
−
b^
p*
)